# ClearCommError(): lpStat not supported?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In the [documentation for ClearCommError()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-clearcommerror) it states that the parameter lpStat is not supported.  What does this mean?  Is ClearCommError() no longer required to work as it used to?

Comment: It belongs to the previous parameter, lpErrors.  CE_TXFULL is not supported.  Perhaps a reviewer noted that it is not an error.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, the manual text is not well formatted. *The following values are not supported* must list values not supported for the parameter `lpError`, but this list is empty. Thus *The following values are not supported* does not make sense at all and does not applicable to the parameter `lpStat`.